# Leaflet Map Exported Using Export Web Map Task Looks Stretched

Tags: leaflet, export, printing

I'm running an Angular application that displays a map using Leaflet, and has a custom print where the user can set some options before sending a request to the ArcGIS Online print service (https://utility.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task/execute). The issue is that the resultant exported map always appears stretched horizontally, so that a polygon that was square will be clearly rectangular. The entire map - basemap and all polygons - are all stretched the same amount, not just the polygons.

Here is the the code that builds the request:

```
let requestParams: any = {
  f: 'json',
  Web_Map_as_JSON: {
    "mapOptions":
      {
        "showAttribution": true,
        "extent": {
          "xmin": map.getBounds().getWest(),
          "ymin": map.getBounds().getSouth(),
          "xmax": map.getBounds().getEast(),
          "ymax": map.getBounds().getNorth(),
          "spatialReference": {"wkid": 4326}
        },
        "spatialReference": {"wkid": 4326},
      },
    "operationalLayers": this.getOperationalLayers(map),
    "exportOptions": {"dpi": printOption.printQualityDPI},
    "layoutOptions":
      {
        "titleText": printOption.title,
        "authorText": printOption.author,
        "copyrightText": printOption.copyright,
        "customTextElements": [{"Date": new DateTimePipe(this.userPreferencesService).transform(new Date())}],
        "legendOptions": {"operationalLayers": []}
      }
  },
  Format: printOption.format,
  Layout_Template: printOption.getParsedLayout(),
  printFlag: true
};

switch (printOption.scalebarUnit) {
  case 'Feet':
  case 'Meters':
    requestParams.Web_Map_as_JSON.layoutOptions.scaleBarOptions = {
      "metricUnit": "esriMeters", "metricLabel": "m", "nonMetricUnit": "esriFeet", "nonMetricLabel": "ft"
    };
    break;
  case 'Kilometers':
  case 'Miles':
  default:
    requestParams.Web_Map_as_JSON.layoutOptions.scaleBarOptions = {
      "metricUnit": "esriKilometers", "metricLabel": "km", "nonMetricUnit": "esriMiles", "nonMetricLabel": "mi"
    };
    break;
}

switch (printOption.preserveOpt) {
  case 'extent':
    // don't do anything. We always set the extent as all options require it (scale uses the center)
    break;
  case 'forceScale':
    requestParams.Web_Map_as_JSON.mapOptions.scale = printOption.forceScaleValue;
    break;
  case 'scale':
  default:
    requestParams.Web_Map_as_JSON.mapOptions.scale = MapUtil.SCALE_ZOOM_LEVEL_MAP[map.getZoom() + 3];
    break;
}

if (requestParams.Layout_Template == 'MAP_ONLY') {
  if (printOption.mapOnlyWidth && printOption.mapOnlyHeight) {
    requestParams.Web_Map_as_JSON.exportOptions.outputSize = [printOption.mapOnlyWidth, printOption.mapOnlyHeight];
  } else {
    requestParams.Web_Map_as_JSON.exportOptions.outputSize = [map.getContainer().clientWidth, map.getContainer().clientHeight];
  }
}
```

The code that builds the operational layers is as follows:

```
  getOperationalLayers(map) {
let pointLayerSpec = {
  "layerDefinition": {
    "name": "pointLayer",
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
    "drawingInfo": {
      "renderer": {
        "type": "simple",
        "symbol": {
          "type": "esriPMS",
          // The following is the map pin icon, converted first to a PNG then to base64. Map Print hates SVG.
          "imageData": "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",
          "contentType": "image/png",
          "width": 16,
          "height": 16
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "featureSet": {"features": []}
};
let polygonLayerSpec = {
  "layerDefinition": {
    "name": "polygonLayer",
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
    "drawingInfo": {
      "renderer": {
        "type": "simple",
        "symbol": {
          "type": "esriSFS",
          "color": MapUtil.PRINT_FILL_COLOR,
          "outline": {"color": MapUtil.PRINT_LINE_COLOR, "width": 1}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "featureSet": {"features": []}
};
let lineLayerSpec = {
  "layerDefinition": {
    "name": "lineLayer",
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolyline",
    "drawingInfo": {
      "renderer": {
        "type": "simple",
        "symbol": {
          "type": "esriSLS",
          "color": MapUtil.PRINT_LINE_COLOR,
          "width": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "featureSet": {"features": []}
};
let layers = [pointLayerSpec, polygonLayerSpec, lineLayerSpec];

let addPointFeature = (geoJSON) => {
  pointLayerSpec.featureSet.features.push({
    "geometry": {
      "x": geoJSON.geometry.coordinates[0],
      "y": geoJSON.geometry.coordinates[1],
      "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 4326
      }
    }
  });
};
let addPolygonFeature = (geoJSON) => {
  polygonLayerSpec.featureSet.features.push({
    "geometry": {
      "rings": geoJSON.geometry.coordinates,
      "hasZ": false,
      "hasM": false,
      "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 4326
      }
    }
  });
};
let addMultiPolygonFeature = (geoJSON) => {
  geoJSON.geometry.coordinates.forEach(coordinates => {
    polygonLayerSpec.featureSet.features.push({
      "geometry": {
        "rings": coordinates,
        "hasZ": false,
        "hasM": false,
        "spatialReference": {
          "wkid": 4326
        }
      }
    });
  });
};
let addLineFeature = (geoJSON) => {
  lineLayerSpec.featureSet.features.push({
    "geometry": {
      "paths": geoJSON.geometry.coordinates,
      "hasZ": false,
      "hasM": false,
      "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 4326
      }
    }
  });
};
let addFeature = (geoJSON) => {
  if (geoJSON.geometry.type === "Point") {
    addPointFeature(geoJSON);
  } else if (geoJSON.geometry.type === "Polygon") {
    addPolygonFeature(geoJSON);
  } else if (geoJSON.geometry.type === "MultiPolygon") {
    addMultiPolygonFeature(geoJSON);
  } else if (geoJSON.geometry.type === "LineString" || geoJSON.geometry.type === "MultiLineString") {
    addLineFeature(geoJSON);
  }
};

map.eachLayer((layer) => {
  if (layer.toGeoJSON) {
    let geoJSON = layer.toGeoJSON();
    if (geoJSON.type === "Feature") {
      addFeature(geoJSON);
    } else if (geoJSON.type === "FeatureCollection") {
      _.forEach(geoJSON.features, (geoJSONFeature) => {
        addFeature(geoJSONFeature);
      });
    }
  }
});
return [
  {
    "id": "defaultBasemap",
    "title": "World Topographic Map",
    "opacity": 1,
    "minScale": 0,
    "maxScale": 0,
    "url": "https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer"
  },
  {
    "id": "map_graphics",
    "featureCollection": {
      "layers": layers
    }
  }
];
}
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with the request, but every single time the map is exported it is stretched. Is there something I need to be doing to the leaflet map before this stage to prevent the stretching? I'm pretty new to these plugins, I don't know where to start.

[image: Map as viewed in app]

[image: Map as viewed in export]

Answer (score 2):

I decided to project the Extent coordinates to Web Mercator.  This solved the "stretched" problem I was having.  It appears the same issue you are having.

Here is a Javascript function I built that converts the current bounds of the map to 3857 and sets up the "mapOptions" part of the Export Web Map JSON.

```
getMapOptions() {
    const bounds = map.getBounds();
    // convert from 4326 to 3857
    let northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
    let southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();

    let extent = {
        "xmin": L.CRS.EPSG3857.project(southWest).x,
        "ymin": L.CRS.EPSG3857.project(southWest).y,
        "xmax": L.CRS.EPSG3857.project(northEast).x,
        "ymax": L.CRS.EPSG3857.project(northEast).y,
        "spatialReference": {
            "wkid": 3857
        }
    };

    return {
        "extent": extent,
        "scale": 7000,
        "rotation": 0
    };
}
```